# How to associate each object in the prediction to its annotated version in YOLOv5?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

Imagine we have one image from the COCO validation dataset. This image has 7 annotated objects: knife, carrot, person, table, chair, apple, and orange. When I feed it to YOLOv5, the predictions are only for person, knife, table, and orange and other objects are missing from predictions.

Now, I should evaluate the model, I want to calculate the IoU for the predicted objects. But my problem how I can associate the annotated object to its corresponding predicted one, especially, the orange and apple have similar shape and size, and also knife and carrot. I want to avoid any mismatch like comparing predicted orange with annotated apple. After a long search, I found there is a unique ID for each annotated object in COCO dataset but this ID is not available for the predicted output.

**My ultimate objective** is to create a dataframe for all objects of the same image with the following columns: ground-truth label, predicted label, annotated width, predicted width, annotated height, predicted height, and IoU. If there is a missing object in the prediction, I set -1 for all columns related to the predictions.

Could you please explain to me how can I associate each object in the prediction to its annotated version?

Thank you so much for your help and time.